# Control Docking Rectangle inside of a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a panel that renders a special header, this works all fine and good - but when I dock other controls inside of that panel, they size to fit underneath the header.

My thought was to try and catch this and control it somewhere. Getting the DisplayArea doesn't work - then the header doesn't draw in the right place. Is there any way I can tell docking to account for the height of the header?

Using C#, Windows Forms, .NET 3.5

Panel : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
Header : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

Panel
{
 Header { get; set; }
}

is the basic structure. It's not terribly complicated.

Comment: I'm a little confused : if you have a Panel that contains a Header/UserControl docked Top (I assume), and you add another UserControl or Panel to the the first Panel and also dock it to 'Top : it will appear underneath the Header/UserControl you added first without any part of it being obscured. Even if you set the second control added's Dock property to 'Fill : it will not obscure the Header/UserControl. So, I need some help to visualize the problem you are describing here.

Comment: No, the header is docked, but if I dock something to .fill, it slides underneath the header.

Comment: Create a Panel, drag in another panel and dock it to the top. Then create another panel and dock it to fill. You'll see what I am experiencing.

Comment: We are talking about adding controls to your Panel at design-time : right ? Try selecting the Header any time anything you've added to the Panel partially obscures the Header, right-click and choose 'Send To Back' : or select anything that has been obscured by the Header and right-click it and choose 'BringToFront.

Comment: Stacey wrote : "Create a Panel, drag in another panel and dock it to the top. Then create another panel and dock it to fill. You'll see what I am experiencing." Hi, no I won't see what you describe : the second panel docked 'Fill will occupy only the space not occupied by the docked top control/Panel/UserControl, and nothing on it will be obscured by the docked Top Header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls are docked in order of their z-order, back to front. When you add a control at run-time it is generally added in back, which means it will be docked before preexisting controls, allowing the new control to sneak under existing controls. It does not matter what order the controls were docked in.

Try calling SendToBack on the header control after adding other controls (or if this is a design time issue, just right-click it and do "Send To Back").

Comment: OP has not yet clarified whether this is run-time scenario. If run-time, the easiest way is just to call 'BringToFront on the control just after it's been added to the container, and its Dock property set.

Comment: I suppose so. Generally speaking it may be a better approach to bring a new control to front to yield to existing docked controls, rather than modifying those pre-existing controls to suit the new one. In this simple case the result is the same.